# Why does this Windows batch file behave differently when operating on a local vs. network path?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I am executing a Windows batch file in Jenkins. Part of the script looks for files matching `*.cover.xml` and runs an external program on each of them. The relevant part of that batch file looks like this

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET project_path=\\home\Sonar\8.1
PUSHD %project_path%
FOR /R %%i IN (*.cover.xml) do ncxc.exe %%i
POPD
```

When I set the `project_path` to a local path, like `D:\MyProj\`, it works perfectly. When I use a UNC path, like above, there's a problem. The first time it runs, it passes. Every time after that, it fails!

> 'ncxc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I ran `DIR` at the end of the script and the directory is empty! The Jenkins service is running as domain user and the `copy` command works with network resources. And `PUSHD` mounts the UNC path to a drive letter.

**EDIT** - the entire batch file which also fails the same way

```
set deployment_path=d:\deployment\
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set project_path=Z:\8.1\
pushd %project_path%
set some_path=%CD%
copy %deployment_path%\sppg.exe %CD%\sppg.exe /y
copy %deployment_path%\sonar_main.bat %CD%\sonar_main.bat /y
copy %deployment_path%\utils_all.bat %CD%\Utils\utils.all.bat /y
copy %deployment_path%\dunit2surefire.xsl %CD%\HCPC\dunit2surefire.xsl /y
copy %deployment_path%\xslt2xml.exe %CD%\HPC\xslt2xml.exe /y
copy %deployment_path%\sonar_delphi_all.bat %CD%\HPC\sonar_delphi_all.bat /y
copy %deployment_path%\xslt.bat %CD%\HCPC\Client\xslt.bat /y
copy %deployment_path%\xslt.bat %CD%\HCPC\Server\xslt.bat /y
copy %deployment_path%\ncxc.exe %CD%\ncxc.exe /y
copy %deployment_path%\ncover-converter.bat %CD%\ncover-converter.bat /y
ncxc.exe %CD%
popd
pushd %project_path%
sppg.exe "%CD%" ./Output_AutomatedBuild/TestsResults/Coverage/*.cover.xml

dir Z:
sonar_main.bat
popd
```

Comment: why enable delayexpansion ? Did you try with a network drive ? Did you try to specify the full path of ncxc.exe ?

Comment: did you remove the network path with `popd`?

Comment: It sounds like you used the variable `path` in your batch file.

Comment: Did you try with a network drive ? Did you try to specify the full path of ncxc.exe ? - Yes

Comment: did you remove the network path with popd? -- Yes

Comment: I assume `ncxc.exe` is in the `PATH` of the Jenkins service user? I'm with @foxidrive at this point, I suspect there's something else in your batch script that's modifying the `PATH`. Can you post the entire thing to the end of your question?

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean I think yes

Comment: Please post the whole batch file, you may remove any paths or names that are identifying of your company or clients. In the meantime, have you looked into psake (powershell) or rake (ruby language) as a build script option? Much nicer than raw Windows commands.

Comment: `set some_path=%CD%` is not used in the batch file.  Is it really there?  `sonar_main.bat` can also be the problem where changing system variables is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

CMD can't start from a UNC path without registry hack.

Your problem seems a little strange. I would recommend to use just the UNC paths for copying.

```
set deployment_path=d:\deployment\
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set project_path=\\server\share

copy %deployment_path%\sppg.exe %project_path%\sppg.exe /y
```

this is no problem at all. try it. I also recommend to never use %cd% because it can't securly rely what is its content.

and for the exe file: just give it's full qualified path.

```
%project_path%\ncxc.exe ...
```